# How can I find the index of the maximum values along rows of matrix Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark, max

I have a question about finding index of the maximum values along rows of matrix. How can I do this in Spark Scala?  This function would be like argmax in numpy in Python.

Answer (score 2):

What's the type of your matrix ? If it's a `RowMatrix`, you can access the `RDD` of its row vectors using `rows`.

Then it's a simple matter of finding the maximum of each vector of this `RDD[Vector]`, if I understand correctly. You can therefore `myMatrix.rows.map{_.toArray.max}`.

If you have a `DenseMatrix` you can convert it to an `Array`, at which stage you'll have a list of elements in [row-major form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). You can also access the number of columns of your matrix with `numCols`, and then use the collections method `grouped` to obtain rows.

```
myMatrix.toArray.grouped(myMatrix.numCols).map{_.max}
```

Comment: Thans for answer. I have DenseMatrix and can't go along rows by rows.map. I tried convert DenseMatrix to RowMatrix by :  val rm: RowMatrix = new RowMatrix(dm)
but it does not work. (

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to get the values as an array to get the maximum value.

```
    val dm: Matrix = Matrices.dense(3, 2, Array(1.0, 3.0, 5.0, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0))

    val result = dm.toArray.max

    println(result)
```