# Row wise maximum of Coordinate Matrix Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

I have a `spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.CoordinateMatrix` called mat and I wish to compute the row wise maximum of this sparse matrix. I know that mat.entries is the rdd which stores contents of mat as `MatrixEntry(i,j,v)`. Now I wish to find the row wise maximum of mat. i.e. I need to find for every i, the maximum value v over all j's. How should I go about doing this?

So far I have this:

```
val mat_RowMatrix = mat.toRowMatrix() // found function toRowMatrix on github 
val max_entries = mat_RowMatrix.rows.map{_.toArray.max}
```

But I need to find argmax (index of the maximum) and not the value itself. Where can I find documentation for this? I think I have to use maxBy but don't know how to use it. Also, is there a better way to do all this?

Some direction would help a lot.

Comment: I saw that this a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29891465/1804173). However, all answers given their do not really address the question, because provide the max and not the index of max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`RowMatrix.rows`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.RowMatrix@rows:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]) gives you an `RDD[Vector]`, and a [`Vector`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector) already provides this functionality by the [`argmax`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector@argmax:Int) function. So you can do:

```
val maxEntries = matRowMatrix.rows.map{_.argmax}
```